# If $u$ is harmonic then $\int_G |\nabla u|^2\leq\int_G |\nabla v|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, harmonic-functions

Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set with smooth boundary and
let $u,v:\bar{G}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $C^2$ functions.   Suppose
that $u$ is harmonic, i.e. $\Delta u=0$, and that $u|_{\partial G}=v|_{\partial G}$.

Prove that:
**1.** $$\int_G |\nabla u|^2=\int_G \left \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \right \rangle$$ 
**2.** $$\int_G |\nabla u|^2\leq\int_G |\nabla v|^2$$

I managed to solve the first part. It's a simple application of the assumptions and Green's identities, more specifically the second one (which can be found at the very beginning of [these notes](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124B/lecs/lec13.pdf)).

However, I'm stuck on the second one.
Using the first part it suffices to show that 
$$\int_G \left \langle \nabla v, \nabla (v-u) \right \rangle\geq 0$$ 
but I cannot proceed from here. 
I'd be glad for someone's help on this one.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz might help.

Comment: I thought about that. But I see no way to guarantee that $|\nabla u|\leq |\nabla v|$

Comment: Using the first equality we have
\begin{equation*}
\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u\right\rvert^{2}dx=\int_{G}\left<\nabla u,\nabla v\right>dx\le\sqrt{\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u\right\rvert^{2}dx}\sqrt{\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla v\right\rvert^{2}dx}
\end{equation*}
now divide by $\sqrt{\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u\right\rvert^{2}dx}$

Comment: Ohhhh I see. That's a different kind of Cauchy-Schwarz than the one I had in mind then. Thanks! You can definitely post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that if
\begin{equation*}
\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u(x)\right\rvert^{2}dx=0
\end{equation*}
then the second inequality is clear. So we may assume this integral is positive. By the equality obtained before we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u(x)\right\rvert^{2}dx&=\int_{G}\left<\nabla u(x),\nabla v(x)\right>dx\le\int_{G}\left\lvert \nabla u(x)\right\rvert\left\lvert\nabla v(x)\right\rvert{}dx\\
&\le\left(\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u(x)\right\rvert^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla v(x)\right\rvert^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
Dividing through by $\left(\int_{G}\left\lvert\nabla u(x)\right\rvert^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and squaring gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more easy way to see this is to write $\nabla v = \nabla (v-u) + \nabla u$. Then, by $\int_G \langle \nabla (v-u) , \nabla u\rangle = 0,$ we have
$$ \int_G |\nabla v^2| = \int _G |\nabla (v-u)|^2 + \int_G |\nabla u|^2 \geq \int_G |\nabla u|^2. $$
This can be thought of some sort of otrhogonal decomposition of $v$, hence the above is just pythagorean (if you like).